# How to return multiple values as part of a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, return-value

I have this function to reposition coordinates to draw objects to my screen

```
>>> def relative_pos(x, y):
...     # do something with x, y
...     return x, y

>>> rectangle = relative_pos(1, 2), relative_pos(3, 4)
>>> rectangle
((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

but I need the function to return the values without a tuple like this

```
>>> rectangle
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the tuples:

```
>>> rectangle = relative_pos(1, 2) + relative_pos(3, 4)
>>> rectangle
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension can be used for this but seems more compliacted and slower than concatenating:

```
rectangle = relative_pos(1,2), relative_pos(3,4)
x = tuple([coordinate for coordinates in rectangle for coordinate in coordinates])
print(x)
```